MoveIt2 move_group_interface (C++) motion planning gets failed
I have a custom 5DOF arm for which I had generated the MoveIt configuration and checked the demo.launch through which I was able to visualize the arm and also was able to do motion plans within Rviz2 GUI Itself. Then following this using Move Group Interface (C++ API, as MoveIt2 (humble branch) doesn't have support for Python API) I modified the C++ program to generate motion plans for a given pose (first sub part alone) and ran both launch files but the motion plan isn't generated and gets failed. Even I tried setting SetGoalTolerance of $1e^-2$ still the plan isn't generated and gets failed. I couldn't find the reason behind why it fails to generate ?
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2: Humble
MoveIt2: Humble, Source Built
